# PHP: How to directly perform dynamic lookup of static properties' elements?

Tags: php, properties, static

Here's the context:

```
<?php

class PVCombo
{

    /**
     * Prefixes by an arbitrary index
     * @var array
     */
    public static $prefix = array(
        '1' => '',
        '2' => 'Mr',
        '3' => 'Mrs',
        '4' => 'Ms',
        '5' => 'Miss',
        '6' => 'Dr',
    );

    /**
     * Suffixes by an arbitrary index
     * @var array
     */
    public static $suffix = array(
        '1' => '',
        '2' => 'Jr',
        '3' => 'Sr',
        '4' => 'II',
        '5' => 'III',
        '6' => 'Esq',
    );

    /**
     * Agnostic call to get a specific property element
     * 
     * @param  string $propName propery name
     * @param  string $idx      index to call
     * @return string           desired element of called property
     */
    public static function get($propName, $idx)
    {
        $temp = self::$$propName; // these two lines,
        return $temp[$idx];       // I'd prefer to be one...
    }
}
```

Ok, there's a drastically reduced version of my actual class, above, but it gets the point across.
My question is related to my get() method.  I wanted to dynamically call to the property ($$propName) and fetch an element directly off of it, 
(calling code):

```
// assume the class file has been included here
$staticProperty = 'prefix';
$index = 2;
$otherStaticProperty = 'suffix';
$otherIndex = 1;

$prefix=PVCombo::get($staticProperty,$index);
$suffix=PVCombo::get($otherStaticProperty,$otherIndex);
// $prefix is 'Mr' and $suffix is ''
```

...but was unable to.  My original return statement to get()
(class code):

```
return self::$$propName[$idx];
```

returned an index error, so instead I assign the property to a temp variable and looked up the element on that (still class code):

```
$temp = self::$$propName;  
return $temp[$idx];       // my compromise return statement on get()
```

...and hey, things work beautifully.  But it seems that there *should* be a way to do it without the 'temp' assignment.
Does anyone know how to directly fetch the element on a dynamic reference of a static property (array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 liner solution (inside the function):

```
/**
 * Get the value of a static array property. Returns NULL if $propName is not an existing static property.
 * 
 * @param string $propName     Name of a static array property
 * @param int    $index        Index of an existing item from $propName
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
static public function get($propName, $index)
{
    return isset(self::${$propName}) ? self::${$propName}[$index] : null;
}
```

The PHPDoc already defines how this works.

Comment: Gracias.  I looked at the PHP Docs, but missed that. (and good point about the isset)

Comment: Aren't we missing the second $ in the second term of that return statement?

Comment: @MattMurphy Ohh yes, updated the answer now. Thanks mate